# How to keep maven runtime dependency available on containers

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Let's say I have 10 Java EE projects(ear). Some of those depends on the package X (plain java package), which is very large. If I add it as compile dependency total project size would potentially grow as 10*(size of X package). I think runtime dependency option is the way to go. But have no idea make the package X available at runtime on containers such as JBoss. How to make plain java packages available at runtime on Java EE containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `runtime` dependency scope, when you mark a dependency `runtime`, it means maven will not add those dependencies in classpath during compilation

for example: if you have slf4j api and if you want to bind it with slf4j-simple at runtime you don't neeed slf4j-simple during compile time, this can be marked as runtime dependency

in your case, even if you don't need them during compile time you will have to pack them because you are building an EAR which needs to have all the dependencies, JBoss won't magically grab those dependencies for you

Comment: so are all my "ear"s would have package X compiled in them and they should all have added extra size?

Comment: Yes unless you think package X is something that jboss provides (for example servlet-api)

Comment: I thought "provided" means the package is provided by the server.